# codeigniter problem, I dont know what's wrong with my MVC

Tags: php, codeigniter

So I don't know what's wrong if it's my controller or my model in my CodeIgniter Framework please help. My tables are not getting the data from my database in my view.

I've tried everything that I've seen in stackoverflow but I can't get it to work but this is my original code.

This is my **controller**:

```
public function index(){

    $data['suppliers'] = $this->dashboard_model->readSupplier();
    $data['items'] = $this->dashboard_model->readItem();
    $data['users'] = $this->dashboard_model->readUser();
    $data['units'] = $this->dashboard_model->readUnit();
    $data['logs'] = $this->dashboard_model->readLogs();

            $this->global['pageTitle'] = 'Dashboard';
            $this->loadViews("pages/dashboard", $this->global, $data);
```

This is my **model**:

```
class Dashboard_model extends CI_Model{

        function readSupplier(){
            $this->db->from('suppliers');
            $this->db->limit(5);
            $this->db->order_by('supplier_id', 'DESC');
            $query = $this->db->get();
            $result = $query->result();
            return $result;
        }

        function readItem(){
            $data = array(
                'categories.category_name',
                'items.item_id',
                'items.category_id',
                'items.brand_name',
                'items.model',
                'items.serial',
                'items.unit_price',
                'items.status',
                'items.location_id',
                'suppliers.supplier_id',
                'suppliers.supplier_name'
            );
            $this->db->select($data);
            $this->db->from('items');
            $this->db->join('categories', 'categories.category_id = 
            items.category_id', 'left');
            $this->db->join('suppliers', 'suppliers.supplier_id = 
            items.supplier_id', 'left');
            $this->db->limit(10);
            $this->db->order_by('item_id', 'DESC');
            $query = $this->db->get();

            $result = $query->result();
            return $result;
}

        function readUser(){
            $this->db->from('users');
            $this->db->limit(10);
            $this->db->order_by('userId','DESC');
            $query = $this->db->get();
            $result = $query->result();
            return $result;
        }

        function readUnit(){
            $data = array(
                'l.location_name',
                'su.su_id',
                'su.unit',
                'su.motherboard',
                'su.processor',
                'su.ram',
                'su.hdd',
                'su.video_card',
                'su.lan_card',
                'su.power_supply',
                'su.location_id',
                'su.comment',
            );
            $this->db->select($data);
            $this->db->from('system_unit as su');
            $this->db->join('locations as l', 'l.location_id=su.location_id', 'left');
            $this->db->limit(10);
            $this->db->order_by('unit', 'DESC');
            $query = $this->db->get();
            $result = $query->result();
            return $result;
        }

        function readLogs(){

            $this->db->from('activities as a');
            $this->db->join('users as u', 'u.userId=a.userId', 'left');
            $this->db->limit(10);
            $this->db->order_by('userId', 'DESC');
            $query = $this->db->get();

            $result = $query->result();
            return $result;
    }
?>
```

This is my **view**:

```
    <th>User ID</th>
    <th>Full Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
        if(!empty($users)):
            foreach($users as $user): ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $user->userId; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $user->firstname." ".$user->lastname; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $user->email; ?></td>
    </tr>
           <?php endforeach;
           endif;
           ?>
```

Comment: What happens in the `loadViews` of your controller?

Comment: Are you trying to load several views? A better way would be to load them individually in you controller method so that data can be passed on.

Comment: yes im trying to load several views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually got in now and its working the only problem that I'm having right now is that it gives me an error about my readLogs function but if I remove the readLogs function, all the tables will display their datas except for Log History. This is the error by the way.

A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1052

Column 'userId' in order clause is ambiguous

SELECT * FROM `activities` as `a` LEFT JOIN `users` as `u` ON `u`.`userId`=`a`.`userId` ORDER BY `userId` DESC LIMIT 10

Filename: E:/Xammp2/htdocs/cri-marc/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691

Comment: Add `ORDER BY u.userId DESC LIMIT 10` instead of `ORDER BY userId DESC LIMIT 10`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in method of yours **controller**: `loadViews`

The way [how to load view](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html) you can see over this link.

I think that in the **model** is all fine. So, you need to check method `loadViews`. And, if you really wanna see some result you can replace next:

```
 $this->global['pageTitle'] = 'Dashboard';
 $this->loadViews("pages/dashboard", $this->global, $data);
```

with

```
$this->load->view('pages/dashboard',$data);
```

*Note: read how to use the third argument of this method `load->view`, it can has value `true` or `false`, by default it's `false`.*

Comment: I changed it to $this->load->view('pages/dashboard',$data); and it won't still display my datas in my tables inside the dashboard, thank you for taking the time to answer sir.

Comment: @nelsonmascarinas, does `dashboard.php` has path `views/pages/`? Inside project dir `views` must be dir `pages` and inside this dir should be `dashboard.php`. Inside this view you can use php variables such as `suppliers,...blablabla...,logs`, which you've sent in `$data`.

Comment: yes the path is views/pages/dashboard.php and what am I going to do with the variables sir?

Comment: `$this->load->model('supplier_model');
            $this->load->model('log_model');
            $this->load->model('peripheral_model');
            $this->load->model('systemunit_model');` I also tried doing it like this

Comment: `$data['suppliers'] = $this->supplier_model->read();
            $data['items'] = $this->peripheral_model->read();
            $data['users'] = $this->log_model->read();
            $data['units'] = $this->systemunit_model->read();` here is my function index